# element only resizable when element has been clicked on jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-resizable

Currently I have multiple elements on the page and they are all resizable.

To stop all the resizable handles from being shown all the time I currently have them set to

```
   $("#selector").resizable({autoHide:true});
```

This makes the resizable handles hidden unless the element has a mouseover event.

What I need is the resizable handles to only show when the element has been clicked on and then the handles to disappear 'onblur'

I cannot seem to find anything in the jquery for this.

Will I have to create a new resizable event for each 'onclick' event?

I am looking for a simple one liner or similar.

Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance

Comment: produce the fiddle so that problem can be triggered.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LsK8L/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use following snippet:

```
$('#selector')
    .attr('tabindex', -1)
    .css('outline', 0)
    .resizable({
    autoHide: true
}).off('mouseenter mouseleave').on({
    focus: function () {
        $(this).find('.ui-resizable-handle').show();
    },
    blur: function () {
        $(this).find('.ui-resizable-handle').hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it

```
 $('#a').on({
   mouseenter : function(){
     $(this).resizable();
   }, mouseleave : function(){
     $(this).resizable('destroy');
   }
 });
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MpwV3/3/)

Comment: I want the element resizable on mouseclick not on mouseover so more like this only the blur isnt working  $('#a').on({
    click : function(){
        $(this).resizable();
    }, blur : function(){
        $(this).resizable('destroy');
    }
});

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you http://jsfiddle.net/Rt2Zd/1/

```
   $(function() {

    $( document ).on('click',"#resizable",function(){
    $( "#resizable" ).resizable();
  });

     $('#resizable').blur(function(){
        $( '#resizable').resizable('destroy');
    });

  });
```

add tabindex to the div else the blur event wont be working.

```
   <div id="resizable" class="ui-widget-content" tabindex="1">
     <h3 class="ui-widget-header">Resizable</h3>
   </div>
```

Comment: need to lose the resizable handle on blur

Comment: @BarryWatts : I have made the changes can have a look.

Comment: Yes that works great, thanks but I have already implemented @A.Wolff 's answer